# How to access views in powerapps

Tags: powerapps

I need to access views in powerapps from the sql server management studio. But in powerapps, it only shows tables. How can I access views. Is there any possibility to access views in powerapps?

Comment: Have you tried scripting a view load to table to work around this?

Comment: Yes - what Alexander said. :(  For my App, I created 2 tables:  refresh table (ID, Activate [int], LastRefresh [datetime]) and a table to store my view in.  I setup a job that will delete from my store and then write the view back into the store if Max(Activate) = 1.  This job runs every 10 seconds - in my app, anytime I update data in the database, I also write a record to the refresh table with a value of 1 in [Activate].  It's working fine so far, for my application, but goodness it'd be nice to be able to see views...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afraid not, atleast not yet.

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/PowerApps-Ideas/PowerApps-must-also-see-SQL-Azure-Queries-not-only-Tables/idi-p/863

Vote for it! 
But apparantly it's in the "Planned" section - So hopefully it comes soon!

Comment: The information is this post is out of date, views are now available

Answer (score 2):

Azure SQL Database views and SQL Server views are now available as a data source from PowerApps directly.  This feature was added in Feb 2018.
Just one thing to note is that when an update to an underlying table is performed from PowerApps, then you will need to Refresh() every view based on that underlying table in order to see the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that the user (SQL Server user) that you gave power apps access to has SELECT rights to the views and it will show up.

i.e.

```
GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[TeamsActionPlanningTrackerView] TO powerapps
```